# Possible to concatenate words and number into a single string in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am wondering if it is possible in matlab to put together words and number into a single non blank string.

For example:

```
a = 160727
b = 'skippy'       
c = 42

I want this to be written as: 

160727_skippy_42
```

Is this possible in matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
s = sprintf('%d_%s_%d', a, b, c)
```

or, depending on the context, you might prefer

```
s = sprintf('%d_skippy_%d', a, c)
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can, as a string.

Use `num2str` and string concatenation. Assuming you created `b` properly (`b='skippy'`):

```
s=[num2str(a), '_', b, '_' ,num2str(c)]
```

This concatenation technique will respect spaces, it will remove then. If you are interested in removing any spaces, use `strcat` instead

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @quinshi consider accepting one of the answers if they solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

For another alternative (simply because I rarely see this function used) there's [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html):

```
>> s = strjoin({num2str(a), b, num2str(c)}, '_')
s = 160727_skippy_42
```